# Trapping the linear navigation inside a dialog box

Tags: google-chrome, accessibility

Is there a way in which I can make sure that the user does not go back outside of a dialog box using linear navigation. I have a javascript which takes care of this in tab-navigation.

Note :

**Linear Navigation** : By linear navigation I do not mean the navigation by using tab key but the linear navigation provided by the screen reader. (In goolge chrome its ChromevoxKey + arrows to move forward or backward). This basically navigates through the DOM and the screen reader reads out the DOM element

Comment: Nick's post may help: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/02/12/making-an-accessible-dialog-box/

Comment: Thanks Ryan :). I actually followed that only. but there is no mention of linear navigation. Linear Navigation and tab navigation are different. Tab navigation works with tab key where as linear navigation is specifically for screen reader to read each node of the dom element. On the google chrome with ChromeVox addon it can be done using Ctrl + arrow keys. On a mobile or tablet for forward navigation swipe left to right or top to botton and vice versa for backward navigation

Answer (score 1):

I came across a hack to achieve this.

The screen reader will only read elements visible to it. So, if I add `"aria-hidden"="true"` attribute to a HTML element, the screen reader will never take the linear focus to that element (Screen reader will never even read the divs and its content marked hidden).

**Hack :** I showed the dialog box as a different `div` inside `body` and kept the main content inside a separate `div` under `body` and added `aria-hidden="true"` to the main content `div` whenever I show the dialog box. As soon as I dismiss the dialog box I remove the aria-hidden attr from the main content div.

```
<body>
    <div id="dialog box"> <--- This is the dialog box ----> </div>
    <div id="main content" aria-hidden="true"> <-- This is the main content --> </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before using onblur events. Onblur listener on whatever modal it is you want to ensure keeps focus(onblur doesn't bubble in all browsers, so this can be tricky, but possible).  When your modal loses focus by some action of the user, just announce that you have forced focus back onto whatever element you wish in the modal.  From a usability standpoint it should be the last object within the modal that had focus.  Be sure to specifically announce that you have done this, as it can be jarring, particularly for non-sited users, anticipating focus to be where they have just directed the AT to place it.

A much better approach would be to announce that the modal was closed when it loses focus.  AT users are use to dealing with modals, and if an AT provides navigation outside of a modal because of website design, an AT user will be acustom to the idea of the modal closing itself, when no long being the focus of interaction.  Much like most modals disappear when a user clicks off the modal onto some other portion of the webpage.  Unless your modal absolutely requires attention before moving on, this approach is much more user friendly.  Particularly for sited keyboard users, relying on ATs for navigation help.

Focus/blur events and bubbling/capturing:
http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/04/delegating_the.html

Comment: I am sorry for not making my point clear.I am not sure if the term "Linear navigation" is really correct.Basically on any android phone with accessibility on, you can swipe your figure left to right and the AT would read the next element of the page. similarly case for right to left, it would read the previous element of the DOM. It does not matter if the element is allowed to receive a focus or not. 

What I am trying to achieve is that if screen reader focus reaches the end of the dialog,the AT should read "End to dialog" and then move back to top instead of going to background.

Comment: My method will work independent of which definition of linear navigation you use, though may need minor modifications, the concept is still sound.  The reason I prefer my method to your answer is it is browser/AT independent.  If your solution works for you, it's fine, but you may find in other browser/AT combinations it won't work.  The aria-hidden attribute is broken in many browsers.